# Allow use of member variable depending on preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    #ifdef CONDITION
    int x = 0;
    #endif

    int y;

    int foo() { 
        #ifdef CONDITION
        return ++x;
        #else
        return 0;
        #endif
    }
}
```

`int x` only exists when I define `CONDITION` - either through a `#define CONDITION` or as a preprocessor definition (`-D CONDITION`)

This has the neat advantage that I can't compile it I use `x` by mistake somewhere when `CONDITION` isn't defined.

For example:
If, by mistake, I write something like:

```
Foo f;
f.x = 10;
```

This will not be allowed to compile when I'm missing `-D CONDITION`

However, we get all sorts of nasty problems when class `Foo` is declared in a header that is used by multiple projects, where preprocessor definitions differ:
 The offset of `y` within `Foo` will be different, resulting in different interpretations of how an object of `Foo` looks.

**The question:**
Is there some way in which I can declare `x` for anyone using `Foo`, but still get some sort of compiler warning/error when I try to use it without defining `CONDITION`?

Comment: ot: `foo` has undefined behavior when `CONDITION` Is not defined

Comment: What problems do you get, by using Foo in different projects? The compilation of `Foo` should not depend on any order of header compilation

Comment: `#ifdef CONDITION  int x; #else  int x_Dont_Touch_Me; #endif` would likely work in practice, though technically it's still an ODR violation.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem  (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ).   Presumably there is some reason (i.e. something you expect to achieve) by requiring that a class only be used if a macro `CONDITION` is defined (which may or may not be a solution to your actual problem).   How about you explain your actual problem, rather than asking for your chosen solution?

Comment: @Peter I think you've misread the example. I want to be able to **always** use `Foo` and its member function `foo()`, I just want `foo()` to do something else (always return zero) when `CONDITION` is undefined. 

But, since I'm using `x` only for that specific function, I don't want to be able to make the mistake of using it whenever `CONDITION` is undefined.

Comment: Seems to me that this is best solved by writing two separate classes. Having a single class with two different behaviors will, as you say, "get all sorts of nasty problems".

Comment: @T.J.Evers - Apart from the fact you edited and *changed* your example since my comment ....    Again, you are restating the solution you want (code that works or does not compile, depending on whether `CONDITION` is defined, but somehow works around the fact you are breaking ODR).    You are ASSUMING - incorrectly - that working around that is a solvable problem.   But, presumably, you want to do it to achieve something.   What is that something?

Comment: That something is getting a warning any time I use `x` when I'm not supposed to. Besides, the example compiles just fine without defining `CONDITION` (it missed the `return 0;` case at first, sorry for that, but it did still compile without it).

Answer (score 1):

Don't make definitions that are visible in headers conditional on macro definitions.

If you need to add different members conditionally, then you must hide those members from the user of the class. This can be achieved with the PIMPL pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is ODR violation. A cleaner approach would have been making `CONDITION` a `bool` template parameter.

But if you take this risk, you can take it in reduced form with difference of `x` only in attribute:

```
class Foo 
{
    #ifndef CONDITION
    [[deprecated("Don'u use with [[condition]] defined")]]
    #endif
    int x = 0;
    int y;

}
```