# Compiler warning/error when using #if on something that is undefined

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Consider the following example:

```
#define FOO false
#if FOO
void foo(){}
#endif
```

Obviously, `foo()` does not exist. But when I forget to define `FOO`, the result is the same:

```
#if FOO
void foo(){}
#endif
```

Is there any way to have `foo() {}` conditionally, depending on `FOO`, but **automatically** yielding a warning or error when `FOO` *has not been defined at all*? (I.E. Without manually using something like `#ifndef FOO - #error`)

Comment: `#ifndef FOO` ?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [If-directive macro comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60779032/10871073)?

Comment: Wouldn't your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62996598/allow-use-of-member-variable-depending-on-preprocessor-directives) answer this?

Comment: @Eljay That's completely redundant; `FOO` is treated as `0` if not defined. OP wants an error instead, not to suppress one. Did you read the question backwards? :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings • I read the misleading title.  The answer should be:  turn on compiler warnings.  If desired, turn on warning-as-error.

Comment: @Eljay Does this give a warning? It shouldn't... (edit: [nope](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0680fdc8db3f288c))

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings • When I turn on `-Wundef`, I get a warning.  If I make warnings-as-errors, `-Werror`, I get an error.  Can you enable warnings with your compiler?

Comment: @Eljay No, my compiler ships without any command-line flags  Okay, cool, surprised that's not in `-Wextra`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings • I had filed a defect that `-Wall` did not enable all warnings.  Then they added `-Wextra`, which still did not enable all warnings.  With **clang** we now have `-Weverything` which does enable all warnings that don't require a parameter (and I suspect some that do require a parameter, with a sensible(?) default).  So, finally, I can opt-out of the noisy warnings I don't care about, instead of trying to opt-in to the warnings I do care about but don't know they exist.

Comment: The way to solve this problem is to use one of the preprocessing facilities designed to solve the problem (`#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, or the `defined` operator).  From the last paragraph, though, it sounds like you want to solve it without using the intended facilities... why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, although using an undefined macro is not an error (it evaluates to `0`), [you can make it one](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bfa06ea8bc0609c8) by adding the following to your GCC or Clang command line:

```
-Wundef -Werror
```

But note that *all* warnings will now be treated as errors, and you will become reliant on build settings. So I prefer the explicit approach of `#else` and an `#error` directive if you intend to rely on this to catch bad configurations.

Comment: It seems that to do more or less the same for MSVC, we combine /W4 and /wd4668

Comment: Correction, /w4668

Answer (score 0):

You might do the following:

```
#if defined(FOO)
void foo() {}
#else
#error FOO is not defined
#endif
```

This code will not compile if `FOO` is not defined. The compiler will report an error.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro function and then there will be a warning:

```
#define FOO() false
#if FOO()
```

Comment: The question is about handling someone forgetting to define `FOO`. You're suggesting remembering to define `FOO`, just defining it differently. I don't think that's really in the spirit of the question. It also breaks the desired actual usage of `FOO`.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I use this pattern in order to cope with the problem that the op mentioned. It’s easier to remember to write FOO() than to verify whether FOO is included.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I would love if the c or c++ standard committee would solve this, but this is the best I’ve found.

Comment: This is the solution my team uses with our project.